# Ограничить количество людей на одной странице при помощи JS/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, laravel

Существует ли возможность на `JS` и `PHP`, чтобы на определенную страницу в один момент времени мог заходить только один пользователь. 
То есть пока страница открыта у пользователя **Х**, другие пользователи не могут на нее зайти. 
Как только пользователь **Х** закроет страницу, другой пользователь может ее открыть.

Cобытия `windows.unload` или `windows.beforeunload` не работают в Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Просто как идея...
Первый файл `help42.php`:

```php
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['bz'] = '1'; // Если понадобится записывать в файл кто на странице находится.
$file = 'people.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
?>
<div>
    <?php if(empty($current)) { // Если переменная пустая, значит страница свободна для просмотра.
        echo '<a href="help37.php">Перейти на страницу</a>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Второй файл `help37.php`:

```php
<?php
?>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div>
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
        </div>
        <input id="123">
    </div>
</body>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function write() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Запрос на первый файл
        xhr.open('POST', 'help44.php', true); // указываем файл
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send( 'key=' + encodeURIComponent('123') ); // Чтобы можно было отслеживать наличие key в php файле, если там ещё будут данные
    }
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function () {
        setTimeout(write, 5000); // Записываем через 5 секунд нахождения на странице.

        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) { // при закрытии страницы
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // готовим второй запрос по очистке файла или записи в БД
            xhr.open('POST', 'help43.php', true); // указываем файл
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.send( 'key=' + encodeURIComponent('124') );

            e.preventDefault();
            var confirmationMessage = "";
            (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
            return confirmationMessage;
        }, false);

        $(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
            return "Вы уверены, что хотите покинуть страницу?";
        });
        $(document).on("submit", "form", function(event) {
            $(window).off("beforeunload");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Третий файл `help43.php`:

```php
<?php
file_put_contents('people.txt', ''); // Очищаем файл
```

Четвёртый файл `help44.php` (в комментах добавил как можно будет отслеживать доп. параметры, описание будет чуть ниже):

```php
<?php
/*$user = $_SESSION['bz'];
$param = file_get_contents('people.txt'); // Получаем запись из файла или БД
if(!empty($param)){ // Если не пустая, то дописываем.
    $param .= ' '.$user;
} else { // Если пустая, то ставим имя или логин USERа
    $param = $user;
}*/

$param = '1';
file_put_contents('people.txt', $param); // Записываем в файл.
```

Теперь суть основной проблемы:
В теории всё должно работать корректно, протестировал на сафари и хром.
Однако, если открыть страницу и моментально её закрыть, то триггер не срабатывает, в чём приличная проблема. 
Для этого добавил время срабатывания 5 секунд перед записью в файл. 
В таком формате всё работает корректно.

Но есть возможность, что в течении этих 5 секунд ещё кто-то зайдёт на эту страницу. 
Для этого по примеру в файле `help44.php` можно записывать в файл не триггер, а имя пользователя из сессии(закомментированные данные).
И добавить ещё один запрос `ajax` из файла с картинкой в обработчик, который будет проверять каждую 1,2 или, например, 5 секунд, количество записей в файле.

К примеру:

```php
$user = $_SESSION['bz'];
$param = file_get_contents('people.txt');

$val = explode(' ', $param); // Разбиваем по пробелу записи(записывали в файл через пробел)
if(count($val) > 1){ // Если записей больше 1
    if($user != $val[0]){ // Если имя из сессии не равна первой записи, то...
        header('Location: help42.php'); // Выкидываем его обратно на страницу с кнопкой.
    }
}
```

Вместо файла можно использовать БД или глобальные переменные.

Comment: > `Однако, если открыть страницу и моментально её закрыть` - можно использовать веб-сокет и "пинговать" сервер.